# how to open download API link and save in a path

Tags: python, api, download, urllib, python-webbrowser

I have API download link : https://api.mypurecloud.de/api/v2/downloads/e7f9eb2060b0f2f0

I want to download and save in a file path.

I tried webbrowser module but it is only open and downloading.

Tried urllib , but it saving the source code of that url page.

Any one help me ?

Comment: see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22676/how-to-download-a-file-over-http)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.